# warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]

Tags: c++, vector

Ошибка в 17 строке. Я уже на компилятор Code Blocks грешу (постоянно перлы выдает).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> words; //создаю вектор со словами
    for (string word; cin>>word; ) //считываю слова
    words.push_back(word); //записываю каждое считанное слово в конец вектора

    vector<string> bleep; //создаю второй вектор с нежелательными словами
    bleep[0]="indian"; //инициализирую первое слово вектора
    bleep[1]="bydlo"; //инициализирую второе слово вектора
    bleep[2]="microsoft"; //инициализирую третее слово вектора

    for (int i=0; i<words.size(); ++i) //создаю цикл, выполняемый то количество раз, сколько пользователь ввел слов в первый вектор
        if (words[i]!=bleep[0] && words[i]!=bleep[1] && words[i]!=bleep[2]) //проверяю, является ли каждое последующее слово первого вектора нежелательным, путем поочередного сравнения его с каждым нежелательным словом второго вектора
            cout << words[i] << "\n"; //в случае не совпадения его с нежелательным словом, вывожу проверяемое слово
        else
            cout << "BLEEP\n"; //в случае совпадения, заменяю проверяемое слово словом BLEEP, как нежелательное
}
```

Comment: Code Blocks  - это не компилятор, это IDE. А какой там будет использоваться компилятор - это нужно смотреть в настройках

Comment: Я не имел ввиду, что Code Blocks == компилятор) Я имел ввиду компилятор в среде Code Blocks)

Comment: Это не ошибка, а предупреждение. Причем это действительно именно предупреждение - ничего нелегального в таком сравнении нет.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, на это ругается?

```
i < words.size()
```

Ну так все верно, `i` у вас знаковый `int`, а `words.size()` - это беззнаковый тип `size_t`.

Вот компилятор и *предупреждает* (warning - это еще не ошибка, но прислушиваться и понимать, что компилятору не нравится, нужно в любом случае) - во избежание недоразумений - что вы сравниваете знаковое и беззнаковое значение.

Обычно это сравнение не выливается ни во что страшное :), но чисто теоретически выполнение преобразования для сравнения может привести к неожиданному результату.

**Update**

Вот рабочий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;          //создаю вектор со словами
    for (string word; cin >> word; ) //считываю слова
        words.push_back(word);     //записываю каждое считанное слово в конец вектора

    vector<string> bleep(3);       //создаю второй вектор с нежелательными словами
    bleep[0]="indian";             //инициализирую первое слово вектора
    bleep[1]="bydlo";              //инициализирую второе слово вектора
    bleep[2]="microsoft";          //инициализирую третее слово вектора

    for (size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) //создаю цикл, выполняемый то количество раз, сколько пользователь ввел слов в первый вектор
        if (words[i]!=bleep[0] &&
            words[i]!=bleep[1] &&
            words[i]!=bleep[2]) // проверяю, является ли каждое последующее слово первого вектора нежелательным,
                                // путем поочередного сравнения его с каждым нежелательным словом второго вектора
            cout << words[i] << "\n"; //в случае не совпадения его с нежелательным словом, вывожу проверяемое слово
        else
            cout << "BLEEP\n"; //в случае совпадения, заменяю проверяемое слово словом BLEEP, как нежелательное
}
```

Но я бы все же делал так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const vector<string> bleep{"indian","bydlo","microsoft"};
    string word;
    while(cin >> word)
        cout << (find(bleep.begin(),bleep.end(),word) ==
                 bleep.end() ? word : "BLEEP") << "\n";
}
```

Comment: У меня программа крашится)

Comment: @CodeMonkey Где и как она крашится? И почему об этом нет ни слова в вопросе?

Comment: @CodeMonkey А в том, что программа крашится сравнение не виновато. Программа крашится из-за того, что вы пытаетесь записать строки в пустой вектор `bleep`  и выходите за границы массива. Чтобы такого не происходило можно создать вектор так: `vector<string> bleep(3);`

Comment: По-прежнему крашится. Думаю, компилятор тупит :(

Comment: Вопрос был как сформулирован? о предупреждении. О нем и ответил. Написали бы, что программа не работает - смотрел бы дальше...

Comment: См. исправленный ответ.

Comment: main.cpp|11|error: in C++98 'bleep' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}';  main.cpp|11|error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' - вот такие, теперь уже точно ошибки, выдает компилятор, на приведенный выше более короткий код(

Comment: Если записать и инициализировать элементы вектора по-другому, тогда она компилируется и работает идеально, если вводить слова в консоль через пробел и заканчивать ввод через enter. Что круто, ведь в предыдущем, громоздком варианте, после ввода слов приходилось прибегать к ctrl+z. Сейчас буду изучать приведенный выше более короткий код, спасибо)

Comment: Для компиляции моего кода вам нужно включить поддержку С++11 в своем компиляторе.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша программа делает запись в вектор по индексам, выходящим за пределы вектора

```
vector<string> bleep;
bleep[0]="indian";
...
```

К процитированному предупреждению эта проблема не имеет никакого отношения.

Либо сразу создавайте вектор с необходимым количеством элементов

```
vector<string> bleep(3);
```

либо используйте `push_back` вместо оператора `[]`.

Comment: vector<string> bleep(3);
    bleep.push_back("indian");
    bleep.push_back("bydlo");
    bleep.push_back("microsoft");  //все тоже предупреждение, уже запускается, но работает не так, как нужно; нежелательное слово не заменяется. Думаю, все же компилятор тупит :(

Comment: @CodeMonkey, примите презумпцию безгрешности компилятора. С ним спорить бесполезно.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Учтите, что наезд на компилятор - де, он ерунду делает, а не я налажал - выдает начинающего программиста с головой...

Comment: @Code Monkey: ??? Ясно же сказано: **либо** `bleep(3)`, **либо** `push_back`. Но не и то и другое вместе. *Разбирайтесь* с тем, что и почему вам советуют, а не просто слепо перепечатывайте буковки/циферки в свой код. Принцип "кашу маслом не испортишь" тут не работает.

Comment: Разумеется, я только начинаю изучение языка. Мне даже в голову не пришло, что существуют такие тонкости и еще вчера мне казалось, что один фиг, как записать вектор (с указанием размера или нет) и как инициализировать элементы вектора. Сейчас же, почитав ваши ответы, у меня неожиданно сложилась в голове четкая картина касательно этого момент в моем коде. Либо безразмерный вектор и добавление элементов по очереди в конец. Либо вектор с размером и по индексам. Всем спасибо, теперь работает как надо!)